# ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (44 bytes) Python

Tags: python, aes, valueerror, pycrypto

I'm having an issue while using the  Crypto.Cipher import AES as follows:

```
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode

def encrypt(self, text):
        if not text:
            return None
        if not text.strip():
            return None
        _key     =  self.key.encode('utf-8')
        _iv      =  self.iv.encode('utf-8')
        text     =  self.pad(text)
        encryptor=  AES.new(_key, AES.MODE_CBC, _iv)
        try:
            return b64encode(encryptor.encrypt(text)).decode('utf-8')
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("Error al encriptar el siguiente texto => {}".format(text))
    def decrypt(self, text):
        if not text:
            return None
        if not text.strip():
            return None
        _key     =  self.key.encode('utf-8')
        _iv      =  self.iv.encode('utf-8')
        text     =  str(text)
        decryptor =  AES.new(_key,AES.MODE_CBC,_iv)
        try:
            result = decryptor.decrypt(b64decode(text)).decode('utf-8')
            return self.clean_text(result)
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("Error al desencriptar el siguiente texto => {}".format(text))
```

But I'm having the following error : `ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (44 bytes)`
I'm sure it has to be something with the decoding at the decrypt function, but not sure yet, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

---

Full class:

```py
class symmetric_custom_tokeniza:

    def clean_text(self, text):
        #Elimina caracteres especiales generados por el padding
        return re.compile('[\\x00-\\x08\\x0b-\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\n\r\t]').sub('', text.strip())
    
    def pad(self,text):
        try:
            block_size= self.block_size
            text = text.encode('utf-8')
            text = text +(block_size-len(text)%block_size)*chr(block_size-len(text)%block_size).encode('utf-8')
            return text
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("Error al generar el padding => {}; tamaño caracteres en utf-8 {}".format(text, len(text)))
    #[ Encrypt - Decrypt BUs ]
    
    def encrypt(self, text):
        from base64 import b64decode, b64encode
        import base64
        if not text:
            return None
        if not text.strip():
            return None
        _key     =  self.key.encode('utf-8')
        _iv      =  self.iv.encode('utf-8')
        text     =  self.pad(text)
        #_key = base64.b64decode(self.key)
        encryptor=  AES.new(_key, AES.MODE_CBC, _iv)
        try:
            return b64encode(encryptor.encrypt(text)).decode('utf-8')
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("Error al encriptar el siguiente texto => {}".format(text))
    def decrypt(self, text):
        import base64
        from base64 import b64decode, b64encode

        if not text:
            return None
        if not text.strip():
            return None
        _key     =  self.key.encode('utf-8')
        _iv      =  self.iv.encode('utf-8')
        text     =  str(text)
        #_key = base64.b64decode(self.key)
        decryptor =  AES.new(_key,AES.MODE_CBC,_iv)
        try:
            result = decryptor.decrypt(b64decode(text)).decode('utf-8')
            return self.clean_text(result)
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("Error al desencriptar el siguiente texto => {}".format(text))
```

Comment: AES keys are 16, 24 or 32 bytes long. 44 bytes smells like a Base64 encoded 32 bytes key. Try to Base64 decode the key. If it does not work, post test data.

Comment: @Topaco Should I  Base64 decode key at the return of the decrypt?

Comment: You should describe in more detail what is happening. You claim that the problem occurs during decryption. Does the encryption work? Was the ciphertext generated with this encryption at all? If yes, post test data. Otherwise post the encryption code. Regarding your question, I would try the lines `_key = self.key.encode('utf-8')` (replace the UTF-8 encoding with Base64 decoding). But all just guessing, because of the missing info.

Comment: I have replaced the following: `_key = base64.b64decode(_key)`  at the encrypt and decrypt and get following error:
`raise ValueError("Incorrect IV length (it must be %d bytes long)" %`
`ValueError: Incorrect IV length (it must be 16 bytes long)`

Comment: This is a new error related to the IV. Obviously you are using data/encodings for key and IV that are not compatible with the code or even invalid. Read my last comment and provide the necessary info and test data. This is just guessing around.

Comment: @Topaco, there is any other way to post here the full class that creates the object for the encryption/decryption? somehow it doesn't let me do it.

Comment: Just Added the Class of creating the object

Comment: Also post the call of the methods along with test data so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Using compatible and appropriately encoded values for key, IV, plaintext and ciphertext, `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` work on my machine (with `clean_text()` commented out, because of bugs). So the problem is related to your data. I therefore vote to close this question until you have posted test data so that the problem is reproducible.

Comment: By the way, PyCryptodome supports PKCS#7 padding, so implementing padding and unpadding is unnecessary.